# Can I fit an MTB freewheel onto my road bike?

Tags: derailleur, freewheel

I am looking to replace  my 7 speed 12-18t freewheel on my old road bike to a different 7 speed (something like 14-28t) for easier hill climbs.

Is it possible to do so and what are some possible problems I might encounter while doing this?

I found some 7 speed freewheels online and they are all advertised for mountain bikes. Can I fit one onto my old road bike? How do I know if the derailleur will still work and the sprockets aren’t too big for it?

My derailleur is an EXAGE 300EX.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: That is a well written question, with all the details required for a relevant answer.  Well done!

Comment: Are you sure it's a freewheel? A quick search suggests that 300EX had 7-speed freehub.

Comment: @ojs 300EX derailleur does not necessarily mean that the wheel has the hub from the groupset

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus of course not. The part that made me suspect it might be freehub was 12t cog, most freewheels have 13t or 14t for the smallest one. A quick search confirmed it that the series had freehub.

Comment: @ojs that is a good point about the smallest sprocket

Answer (score 1):

Most freewheels use the ISO standard thread and are interchangeable. Some hubs have a 'British' or 'Italian' thread which are very slightly different but still interchangeable. See [the Sheldon Brown page on freewheels.](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html)

I don't know where to look up the specs of older Shimano derailleurs. Googling for examples for sale on EBay etc. and looking for specs included in the product description suggests:

- Min sprocket: 12t
- Max sprocket: 28t
- Total capacity: 28T

So you should be good with a 14-28 freewheel.

Comment: And if the derailleur pulley hits the cluster on the low gears, you can add a wolf creek roadlink which should fix it:. https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/products/roadlink